# What is a context switch?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was reading about the `debuggerstepperboundary` attribute and a site says it is is useful in a context switch.

What exactly is a context switch? I'm assuming it is a switch from one thread to another, or in execution or security context? However, these are not particularly educated guesses so I'm asking here.

Comment: Your question is interesting, please consider adding more tags (operating-systems, kernel, processes...) and removing the C# tag from it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Context switch is the switching of the CPU from one process/thread to another process/thread.

People sometimes use the term context switch outside of the specific computer world to reflect what they are doing in their own lives. "If I am going to answer that question, I need to context switch from thinking about A to thinking about B".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)

Answer (score 33):

A context switch (also sometimes referred to as a process switch or a task switch) is the switching of the CPU (central processing unit) from one process or thread to another.

Context switching can be described in slightly more detail as the kernel (i.e., the core of the operating system) performing the following activities with regard to processes (including threads) on the CPU: (1) suspending the progression of one process and storing the CPU's state (i.e., the context) for that process somewhere in memory, (2) retrieving the context of the next process from memory and restoring it in the CPU's registers and (3) returning to the location indicated by the program counter (i.e., returning to the line of code at which the process was interrupted) in order to resume the process.

A context switch is sometimes described as the kernel suspending execution of one process on the CPU and resuming execution of some other process that had previously been suspended. Although this wording can help clarify the concept, it can be confusing in itself because a process is, by definition, an executing instance of a program. Thus the wording suspending progression of a process might be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

It usually refers to switching between threads or processes.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) has a more thorough description.

Answer (score 1):

It is the process of switching between processes on a CPU.

Answer (score 0):

> Switching the CPU core to another process requires performing a state
>   save of the current process and a state restore of a different
>   process. This task is known as a ***context switch***

Excerpted from: Operating System Concepts, Abraham (Dinosaurs coverpage)

---

But it doesn't necessarily help me to understand the concept. I like to see animations or images as studying. So, [the RTOS's link](http://web.archive.org/web/20171119164253/http://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00006.html) is genuinely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

context switching is basically switching of the processes a &b , like when the CPU is executing 'a' process , CPU has all the registers fill with 'a' process registers like program counter(which is used to execute a line in the process(process is a term which is used for a program under execution)) ,
stack pointer,base pointer etc... and when you have opened process 'b' from the background programs(not process) , so the kernel(which does all the process management part in the OS (OS is a module and kernel is sub module which does the process,memory,i/o,file management)) , so what the kernel does is , change all the registers with the new process(not program as it will be in running state now)(*previous will be in ready state or (*if it does any i/o then it will be wait state))  , so the CPU will be able to execute the process
that has been loaded by the kernel and CPU fetch the instructions with using the (PC-program counter) and execute the program

(all the state , registers like PC(program counter),SP(stack pointer),BP(base pointer) these all will be stored in program control block of the process(when it is in execution use this or use program term))  and for all the programs there will be process table which has the entries and that entry only we call it as process control block(PCB))   ,where PCB is stored in RAM which is only accessible to kernel and not to user , how?(RAM is divided into two parts user space and kernel space)

Comment: and the speed of the loading depends upon the RAM and type of memory you use(SSD or HDD) , while switching we are fetching the info from the RAM and memory so based upon wich you use , matters for speed (RAM-DDR4 etc....)