# How is starting and stopping the tasks in OS done?

Tags: c, operating-system, context-switch

Trying to do some practicing with context-switching I found following problem:

context saving and restoring does not seem to be a problem, but starting and stopping a task seems a little bit tricky.

While setting up a task is only setting up properly PC register, stack pointer and some registers, then problem is, when the tasks ends then we have got no control over what it's gonna do next (we do not know the return address).

I came up with two solutions to this problem:

1. Set up return address to the procedure, that tells OS to kill, deallocate memory connected with the task and remove task from the queue.
2. Wrap function, which is to be started into another one, that takes as argument pointer to called function.

Second solution could look like more less like following

```
void pre_startup(void(*funct)){
    funct();
    task_end();
}
```

As argument we set proper register to be a pointer to the task.

My question is:

How do OSes deal with the described problem? Do they use one of mentioned solutions or there is some different method to deal with this in a better way?

Comment: Starting a thread is usually done by setting up the new stack with a 'syscall interrupt frame' at the end, (with the return address set to the executable entry point), setting the stack pointer at the frame and performing an interrupt-return.  Thereafter, comms with the OS happens via syscalls/interrupts, and typically a language runtime will set up a call to user 'main' code as in your example(2), and  'task_end()' would be 'terminateProcess' syscall or similar.

Comment: 'we do not know the return address' - doesn't need it.  'terminateProcess' CALLS the OS, and never returns.  The OS sets all non-running thread states to 'never run again' and hardware-interrupts any cores running other threads of the process to stop them.  Once all the process threads are stopped, the OS can cancel/release IO resources and deallocate memory.  The process is then gone.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit thank you, it is very usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most platforms, a startup function in the C runtime will call `exit()` after `main()` returns, e.g.

```
void _start(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    // call initializers...
    int r = main(argc, argv, envp);
    // call finalizers...
    exit(r);
}
```

Comment: I assume, that exit() is the one responsible for letting OS know, the task is over?

Comment: Correct. `exit()` is a system call.

Answer (score 1):

This is all system specific but, at a high level, you can implement exit () or its equivalent by:

1. Entering the kernel mode exit handler.
2. Invoke the scheduler and do a context switch to a new process.
3. Do the processing necessary to delete the first process.
4. Return from the exception in the new process.

Answer (score -1):

They use the memory controller to move memory around - this swaps whole sections of memory, which includes all the heap, stack and executables, restore the registers, Program Counter, stack pointer. etc. See:

[What is a context switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300167/what-is-a-context-switch)

[Context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your anwer. My particular question was about the problem of what exactly happens when the task ends and how it is handled :)

Comment: The process is removed from the task list, so it won't be switched in again.  All memory is returned to the OS heap.  Any file handles, event handles etc are closed.  Any resources used by the process are returned to the OS or closed.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but something must trigger this and the question is how this trigger is implemented. On low level stuff, the task function just does another return statement (ret instruction or something else), so the OS does not know whether the task is finished or not.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your question better now.  All processes have an executable attached to it.  If you look at the simplest C example, the method `int main() { return 0; }`.  When task is started,  OS code calls main().  When main() returns, it passed control back to the OS code, and thus the OS knows it can remove the process from the process-list.

Comment: I think it might not be that simple, usually OS and User programs have two different stacks, therefore, when main returns it's not so obvious where it returns. In other words, how should we make this return return to a meaningful place for OS. Please see answer from duskwuff.

Comment: Calling exit() from anywhere in your C program, or as @DuskWuff points out, in the _start() function, calls the operating system to halt the task immediately.